# Core data seems to fetch empty objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

In my iOS app, im trying to save values via core data to an sqlite db in one view and then retrieve in another. Looking at the database, the save looks to be working fine, objects are in the db as expected. If i then go to my collection view, the result appears correctly. However, if i quite the app and reopen, upon retrieval the collection view displays the correct number of cells(rows) but all are empty???
The fetch count always returns 0 but having set up command line args to see the sql, it suggests that it fetches the correct number of rows. My fetch request is as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"surname" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
NSLog(@"fetch count %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[theFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]]);
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

and this produces the following log for the sql via the command line args tool:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZPLAYER t0 ORDER BY t0.ZSURNAME DESC
2015-02-09 23:56:39.522 teamPicker[290:20878] CoreData: annotation: sql    connection fetch time: 0.0013s
2015-02-09 23:56:39.523 teamPicker[290:20878] CoreData: annotation: total   fetch execution time: 0.0020s for 4 rows.
2015-02-09 23:56:39.562 teamPicker[290:20878] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZEMAIL, t0.ZFORENAME, t0.ZMOBNUM, t0.ZMUGSHOT, t0.ZSURNAME, t0.ZTWITTER, t0.ZPROFILE FROM ZPLAYER t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZSURNAME DESC LIMIT 20
2015-02-09 23:56:39.711 teamPicker[290:20878] CoreData: annotation: sql   connection fetch time: 0.1408s
2015-02-09 23:56:39.711 teamPicker[290:20878] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.1495s for 4 rows.
```

As you can see, it appears to run two queries which i find strange but as im a noob, i wouldnt know if this isnt just how it works. What it does seem to suggest though is that despite the fetch count reporting 0, it has fetched 4 rows, which at this point is all thats in there

Here are my collection view datasource methods in case that helps:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource
// 1
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id  sectionInfo =
[[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
// 2
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}
// 3
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Player *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
playerPhotoCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"playerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.playerImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:info.mugshot];
cell.playerLabel.text = info.forename;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
return cell;
}
```

Ive probably made some glaring and basic errors but im damned if i can spot them or find any answers. I'd be most grateful if anyone can help point me in the right direction. Thanks for reading

EDIT: thanks to pbasdf for pointing out the fault in my call to count the fetch, i moved this code to the appropriate place and it is indeed returning the correct number of objects

As latterly promised, my playerPhotoCell is simply a script with two properties in the h file to act as outlets for an image view and a label that i added to the cell in the storyboard. There are no methods in the .m file as i thought that my viewController code could simply reference the outlets and set their values - indeed this seems to work if you view within the same session as you have saved as the cell is populated correctly - the problem arises when the app has been closed and reloaded - the correct number of cells are loaded but all simply have a white background and no information

Further EDIT:
As suggested, i added a simple check to cellForItemAtIndexPath to see if the values are being populated correctly and they are not, they are in fact null. THe updated method is as follows:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Player *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    playerPhotoCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"playerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.playerImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:info.mugshot];
    cell.playerLabel.text = info.forename;
    if(info.mugshot){
        NSLog(@"Player Image is of type %@", NSStringFromClass([info.mugshot class]));
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}
```

The NSLog of info.mugshot is not called as it fails the condition. However, if you then go and add a new player in and then go back to the viewcontroller view in the same session, the NSLog reports the player image to be type of NSconcreteMutableData and populates the cell correctly along with the correct number of blank cells. If you close the app and dismiss then go back in, it just returns the correct number of empty cells.

EDIT: Add new player code (warning: potentially hazardous code!! ;)

```
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender {
    self.player = [Player alloc];
    self.player.mugshot = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_chosenImage, 1);
    self.player.forename = fName.text;
    self.player.surname = sName.text;
    self.player.email = email.text;
    self.player.mobNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[mobNum.text integerValue]];
    if(twitHandle){
        self.player.twitter = twitHandle.text;
    }

    self.profile = [Profile alloc];
    self.profile.position = position.text;
    self.profile.type = _pressedBtnName;
    self.profile.workRate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(wrRating) ];
    self.profile.stamina = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(stRating)];
    self.profile.skill = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(skRating) ];
    self.profile.finishing = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(fiRating)];
    self.profile.passing = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(paRating)];
    self.profile.strength = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(strRating)];

    NSEntityDescription *playerEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newPlayer = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:playerEntityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPlayer setValue:self.player.forename forKey:@"forename"];
    [newPlayer setValue:self.player.surname forKey:@"surname"];
    [newPlayer setValue:self.player.email forKey:@"email"];
    [newPlayer setValue:self.player.mobNum forKey:@"mobNum"];
    [newPlayer setValue:self.player.twitter forKey:@"twitter"];
    [newPlayer setValue:self.player.mugshot forKey:@"mugshot"];

    NSEntityDescription *pattrEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newPlayerAttr = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:pattrEntityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.position forKey:@"position"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.type forKey:@"type"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.workRate forKey:@"workRate"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.stamina forKey:@"stamina"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.skill forKey:@"skill"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.finishing forKey:@"finishing"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.passing forKey:@"passing"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:self.profile.strength forKey:@"strength"];

    [newPlayer setValue:newPlayerAttr forKey:@"profile"];
```

At this point, i realise i shouldnt need to set the inverse as its defined in the model but if i didnt via the following line, i got an error - again bad but just wanted to get something working

```
[newPlayerAttr setValue:newPlayer forKey:@"player"];

if (newPlayer.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![newPlayer.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
           // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
           }
}
```

The Player and profile objects are just instances of those class which were created from the respective entities in the model. Their files basically just contain a property for each Entity attribute

Querying the sqlite db suggests that the data is being written correctly

For info, in my cellforitematindexpath i put in an NSLog to output the type of [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:indexPath] and it came back with Player. So, on that basis ive no idea why creating the Player instance info and setting it to this then does not work but the properties of info are null

EDIT:
I have added a fetch request to my app delegate and perform this at the end of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method like so:

```
NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
    NSLog(@"fetch count %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]]);
    Player *ken = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects firstObject];
    NSLog(@"Surname %@",ken.surname);
```

The fetched object count reports 6 which is correct. However, the next line that tries to assign fetchedObjects first object to an instance of Player called Ken produces output on the next line of 'Surname (null) which really is just marvellous*. Anyway, perhaps my code is wrong there but it seems the object is not being set at all let alone the attributes because i also did a test (not shown in code snippet) of the ken object such as if(ken){... which was never met. Anyway going to scream into a pillow for a while and maybe do a little cry

*intensely annoying

Comment: self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
This above line should be 
_fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController, using self you again and again call - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController.

Comment: Hi Sandy, thanks for pointing this out - i'd completely missed your comment earlier so apologies for not replying sooner. I'll look into this and see if it helps. Thanks again

Comment: If you log the value of the `info` Player objects in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, are those objects' properties (ie. mugshot, forename) correctly populated?

Comment: right, the problem appears to be in my datasource method as running a simple test as you suggested above, the info.mugshot value is null. No idea why however. I'll add the code above as an edit

Comment: So your `Player` objects are being created and inserted into the database OK, but the attribute values are not being saved correctly.  Can you show the code where you insert the new objects, set their attributes and save the context?  Thanks

Comment: Also, your NSEntityDescription call uses `self.context`, while your FRC initialiser uses `context` - are they the same?

Comment: I think they should be the same yes but thats the result of me panic-trying anything without real knowledge of what i was doing!!! At that point i suspected my context save wasnt working. Will post creation code as an edit - WARNING: its probably terrible code, i was just trying to get it to work ;) For completeness thought, i create the context in the app delegate and set the context of the root view controller in there, i then simply pass the context via segue to each of the views as they are navigated to - ive never been confident whether this is the right or wrong method but seemed to work

Comment: I can't see anything in the `saveBtn` code to cause your problems, though for `self.profile` and `self.player` you shouldn't use just `alloc`. Embed it in `initWithEntity`, as you do for `newPlayer` and `newPlayerAttr`.  But since you say that querying the SQLite DB directly suggests that the save is working OK, I'm rather at a loss as to where your problems lie.  And passing the context around via the segues should be fine.  I can only suggest writing a separate fetch request in AppDelegate, as soon as the context is set, to test whether the object attributes appear null at that point.

Comment: Im pulling my hair out to be honest. Will try writing a fetch in teh app delegate though, thats a good idea. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I feel your pain - have had similar frustrations in the past.  But `ken.surname` being null does point back to the `saveBtn` code being the problem.  As a double check, what results do you get if you use `NSLog(@"Ken is %@", ken);` after that fetch in the AppDelegate?

Comment: Including the line i get:
Ken is <Player: 0x14db1fc0> (entity: Player; id: 0x14daf5c0 <x-coredata://7611C2FB-211F-4D1A-A53C-7EE44BBADBF6/Player/p1> ; data: <fault>)

which gave me a crumb of hope we were getting closer.. until i quickly realised that is just faulting and meant to happen. In the FRC method, after the fetch request is initialised, i tried to set 

[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

but it made no difference and i get the same output. I also added a line to output ken.forename which results in:

2015-02-13 20:14:15.751 teamPicker[200:5682] Kens name is (null)

Comment: OK, so that reconfirms my theory that the objects are getting saved, but not the attributes, which points back to the saveBtn: code.  I will update my answer with a reworking of that.

Comment: Hi again pbasdf, thanks very much for your edit, really appreciate your ongoing time helping with this. The Player and Profile object code is kind of legacy that i was actually going to take out and then didnt bother as it was working (initially i didnt bother permanently saving was just wanting to get views working and it was functioning fine). I do agree it should come out as it is a bit pointless - they dont get saved they are just instances of the Player/Profile entity classes that are set with user input and then used to set the values for the NSManagedObject before save. Anyway, made..

Comment: suggested changes but sadly it hasnt made any difference, still empty cells after closing/reopening app. I had to add the line to set the profiles player attrib back in as well as it was giving an error due to empty player attrib in profile otherwise. Also, its currently creating two identical cells when saving instead of one!!!
I can still see that the data was added to the db however and using sqlite tool in terminal can query ZPLAYER and it returns all the rows with attributes set exactly as they should be. Data is in the database but for some reason the fetch doesnt get the attributes

Comment: Sorry that didn't work out.  I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, but wish you luck in sorting it.

Comment: No problem, thanks again for taking the time to help. If I find a solution I'll make sure to update this thread

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I eventually found the solution to this problem and it was that the Player class did not properly initialise properties etc.. so that when i was creating an instance of this class, the properties weren't initialised and so were null. I added an initialisation method the Player.m file and removed the synthesize  statements and everything kicked into life. I'll post the method i used later.

Many thanks to pbasdf for all help on this, without which i wouldnt have gotten near the answer - a credit to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the fetched results controller to actually perform the fetch.  Insert something like this in the `fetchedResultsController` code, just before the `return _fetchedResultsController;` line:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Fetch error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

**EDIT**

I believe your problems might lie in the code which saves the objects.  As mentioned in comments, you cannot use `alloc` without immediately using an initialiser.  For NSManagedObjects (and subclasses) the designated initialiser is `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.  But I'm guessing you don't want `self.player` and `self.profile` added to the database AS WELL AS newPlayer and newPlayerProfile.  So I suggest rewriting as follows:

```
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender {
    NSEntityDescription *playerEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newPlayer = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:playerEntityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPlayer setValue:fName.text forKey:@"forename"];
    [newPlayer setValue:sName.text forKey:@"surname"];
    [newPlayer setValue:email.text forKey:@"email"];
    [newPlayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[mobNum.text integerValue]] forKey:@"mobNum"];
    if(twitHandle){
        [newPlayer setValue:twitHandle.text forKey:@"twitter"];
    }
    [newPlayer setValue:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_chosenImage, 1) forKey:@"mugshot"];

    NSEntityDescription *pattrEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newPlayerAttr = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:pattrEntityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:position.text forKey:@"position"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:_pressedBtnName forKey:@"type"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(wrRating)] forKey:@"workRate"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(stRating)] forKey:@"stamina"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(skRating)] forKey:@"skill"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(fiRating)] forKey:@"finishing"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(paRating)] forKey:@"passing"];
    [newPlayerAttr setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(strRating)] forKey:@"strength"];

    [newPlayer setValue:newPlayerAttr forKey:@"profile"];
    // You are right, you shouldn't need the next line
    // [newPlayerAttr setValue:newPlayer forKey:@"player"];

    // Not sure whether self.profile and self.player are used elsewhere,
    // So set them to the newly created objects:
    self.player = newPlayer;
    self.profile = newPlayerAttr;

    if (newPlayer.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![newPlayer.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, the perform fetch code is in my viewDidLoad method of the collectionViewController.m file - apologies i should have specified that

Comment: OK.  In which case, the NSLog in your fetchedResultController code happens before the performFetch, which explains why it returns zero.

Comment: ha yes of course! Bl00dy hell, a silly mistake! I guess i'll move the code and check the fetch count first before proceeding so as not to waste any more of anyones time as it may give better clues as to the problem. Thanks for your replies, very much appreciated

Comment: Turning to your empty cells, how are the PlayerPhotoCells built - prototype cells in a storyboard, or class/nib registered with the collectionView?

Comment: Also, don't worry about the FRC doing two fetches from the SQL store - I think this is normal.  I assume it is a performance optimisation.  The first fetch just gets the primary keys, so the FRC can determine row counts etc, the second fetch gets the actual object data.

Comment: Right, i thought (hoped) that may be the case but included it in case i was wrong. As regards the playerPhotoCells, they were prototyped in the storyboard in so much as i linked the default cell that you get when you add a collection view controller, to a playerPhotoCell script that i created. The script basically has all of the properties that i would want to display about a player such as image and a title (name). I think it works as it initially displays the data just not when going back to the app. I'll post the code though when im at my machine tonight. Thanks again for all your time

Comment: Another interesting/strange thing to add was that my app wasnt displaying the data at all until i changed the cacheName to nil in the frc. After this change it does show the data if you stay in the app and go to the collection view but not if you close the app (proper close so it stops running) and reopen later.

Answer (score 0):

Craigen's Feb 10 '15 comment helped me (Core Data noob) after many fruitless hours of seeing null values in cells or just missing rows, and wondering how I could have a row count from a fetch that seemed correct but  never matched my NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo numberOfObjects.  Changing the NSFetchedResultsController cacheName to nil suddenly brought my missing rows into the tableview and it all finally made sense.